# How do I save a decimal number as hexadecimal on a single byte?

Tags: c, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 255;
    char hex[4] = {0};
    hex[0] = 0x02;
    hex[1] = 0x20;
    hex[2] = 0xef;
    hex[3] = x;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%X ", hex[i]);
}
```

This outputs " 2 20 FFFFFFEF FFFFFFFF". What should be changed so that it would output "02 20 EF FF"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is the data overflowed. `char` is -128 ~ 127, when 0xef = 239.
So you can use type `int` or `short` or just `unsigned char` , like that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 255;
    unsigned char hex[4] = {0};
    hex[0] = 0x02;
    hex[1] = 0x20;
    hex[2] = 0xef;
    hex[3] = x;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%02X ", hex[i]);
}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Changing the char to unsigned char worked as well.

Comment: The signed-ness of `char` is implementation defined. And there is only a minimum guaranteed range for `((un)signed) char`. There is no guarantee the range is `-128..127`.

Comment: Use `unsigned char` instead of int for x and hex if numbers are always below or equal to 255.